# How to store association rules from RapidMiner into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, rapidminer, fpgrowth

I need to export fp-growth association rules from RapidMiner to a MySQL database.
The table contains those columns: `premises`, `conclusion`, `support` and `confidence`.

Which operator should I use?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the "Association Rules to ExampleSet" Operator from the [Converters extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_converters), available at the RapidMiner marketplace. The relevant attributes from the resulting example set can be easily stored in a database.
See the sample process below for an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.0.002">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.0.002" expanded="true" name="Process" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="68" name="Iris" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="45" y="120">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="discretize_by_frequency" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Discretize by Frequency" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="179" y="120">
        <parameter key="number_of_bins" value="5"/>
        <parameter key="range_name_type" value="short"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="nominal_to_binominal" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Nominal to Binominal" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="313" y="120">
        <parameter key="transform_binominal" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="use_underscore_in_name" value="true"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="concurrency:fp_growth" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="FPGrowth" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="447" y="120">
        <parameter key="min_support" value="0.1"/>
        <parameter key="find_min_number_of_itemsets" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="min_number_of_itemsets" value="1"/>
        <enumeration key="must_contain_list"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="create_association_rules" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="Create Association Rules" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="581" y="120"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="converters:rules_2_example_set" compatibility="0.4.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Association Rules to ExampleSet" width="90" x="782" y="136"/>
      <connect from_op="Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Discretize by Frequency" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Discretize by Frequency" from_port="example set output" to_op="Nominal to Binominal" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Nominal to Binominal" from_port="example set output" to_op="FPGrowth" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="FPGrowth" from_port="frequent sets" to_op="Create Association Rules" to_port="item sets"/>
      <connect from_op="Create Association Rules" from_port="rules" to_op="Association Rules to ExampleSet" to_port="rules input"/>
      <connect from_op="Association Rules to ExampleSet" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="90"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="18"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: thnx for your response . when I restart the rapidminer, the converters extension version is incompatible.  and in the list of operators, there are no converters operators. I'm working on rapidminer version 9.0.0 and the converters extension version is 0.4.000.

Comment: Hi - did you install text processing extension? Converters requieres it.